# Cannot read property 'x' of undefined (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, oop, canvas

I am currently trying to build a snake game from a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uU5YPIvJ24Y) in JavaScript and Canvas. Currently I am a receiving an error on this line: `grid.set(FOOD, randPos.x, randPos.y);` which is part of the `setFood` function towards the bottom.  I dont understand where the `.x` is coming from because I dont see a X or Y defined within that scope. Would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction so I can finish my first game!!! Thanks.

```
<script>
    //CONSTANTS
    var COLS=26;
    var ROWS=26;

    //ID's
    var EMPTY=0;
    var SNAKE=1;
    var FOOD=2;

    //Direction
    var LEFT=0;
    var UP=1;
    var RIGHT=2;
    var DOWN=3;

    var grid = {
        width: null, 
        height: null,
        _grid: null,

        init: function(d,c,r){
            this.width = c;
            this.height = r;

            this._grid = [];
            for(var x=0; x<c; x++){
                this._grid.push([]);
                for(var y=0; y < r; y++){
                    this._grid[x].push(d);
                }
            }
        },

        set: function(val,x,y){
            this._grid[x][y] = val;
        },

        get: function(x,y){
            this._grid[x][y];
        }
    }

    var snake = {
        direction: null,
        last: null,
        _queue: null,

        init: function(d,x,y){
            this.direction = d;
            this._queue = [];
            this.insert(x,y);
        },

        insert: function(x,y){
            this._queue.unshift({x:x, y:y});
            this.last = this._queue[0];
        },

        remove: function(){
            return this._queue.pop();
        }
    }

    function setFood(){
        var empty = [];
        for(var x=0; x<grid.width; x++){
            for(var y=0; y<grid.height; y++){
                if(grid.get(x,y)===EMPTY){
                    empty.push({x:x, y:y});
                }
            }
        }
        var randPos = empty[Math.floor(Math.random()*empty.length)];
        console.log("working");
        grid.set(FOOD, randPos.x, randPos.y);
        console.log("working???")
    }

    //Game objects
    var canvas, ctx, keystate, frames;

    function main(){
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = COLS*20;
        canvas.height = ROWS*20;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2D');
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);

        frames = 0;
        keystate = {};

        init();
        loop();
    }

    function init(){
        grid.init(EMPTY, COLS, ROWS);

        var sp = {x:Math.floor(COLS/2), y:ROWS-1};
        snake.init(UP, sp.x, sp.y);
        grid.set(SNAKE, sp.x, sp.y);

        setFood();
    }

    function loop(){
        update();
        draw();

        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
    }

    function update(){
        frames++;
    }

    function draw(){
        var tw = canvas.width/grid.width;
        var th = canvas.height/grid.height;

        for(var x=0; x<grid.width; x++){
            for(var y=0; y<grid.height; y++){
                switch(grid.get(x,y)){
                    case EMPTY:
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
                        break;
                    case SNAKE:
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#0ff";
                        break;
                    case FOOD:
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
                        break;
                }
                ctx.fillRect(x*tw, y*th, tw, th);
            }
        }
    }

    main();
</script>
```

Comment: Just to clarify. I understand why I am receiving the error(because there is no x within the scope) but I am having trouble back tracking to understand where I messed up.

Comment: x is the value of the item in your loop. Its not the x that is the problem here but `randpos` which is `undefined`

Comment: Let me help you debug: `grid.set(FOOD, randPos.x, randPos.y);` is giving you an error saying you're trying to get the `x` property from something that's undefined. So `randPos` is undefined. `randPos` comes from `empty[Math.floor(Math.random()*empty.length)];`. `empty` is an array created inside a nested for loop: `empty.push({x:x, y:y});`. Do you see where `x` is coming from?

Comment: @Steez: Are you 200% sure this is the actual code you are running? We all make mistakes, but I have been looking at the single responsible line of code here and my current conclusion is "that cannot possibly happen".

Comment: @Steez: ...and true to rubber duck debugging experience, saying this out loud let me spot a problem: this would happen if the array `empty` does not contain even a single item, i.e. when *all* the squares in your grid are non-EMPTY. Now that I am on the right track, it's easy to see that in your code you are setting cells to `FOOD` and to `SNAKE`, but never back to `EMPTY`. So eventually all of the grid would end up non-empty.

Comment: Thank you @bbill That helps point me in the right direction but doesnt really fix my problem. I now understand that randPos = empty[0] which is undefined but why would he call .x on an undefined???

Comment: @Jon Yes when I open the DOM it points to this error. Although I am positive the problem stems from somewhere else.

Comment: Doesn't your `get: function(x,y){` actually need to `return this._grid[x][y];`, otherwise the returned value will be `undefined`.

Comment: Haven't noticed this comment before. You probably noticed the error few moments before I did, so Yours should be chosen.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `setFood` function. Few lines above the line where You get the error, there is a loop that fills the `empty` collection with objects containing both `x` and `y` fields. One of those objects is than assigned to `randPos` variable.

The error is caused probably by invalid assignment of the value to `randPos` variable. It's undefined, so it does not contain required `x` field.

**UPDATE**

It seems that You just missed the `return` keyword in Your `grid.get(x,y)` function, so it should look like this:

```
get: function(x,y){
        return this._grid[x][y];
    }
```

Please verify if adding it solves Your issue.

Comment: But *why* does this happen? Especially given the relevant code fragment, which looks totally legit.

Comment: Make sure if this is ever true: `grid.get(x,y)===EMPTY`. I mean, check if the code goes inside the loop and calls `empty.push({x:x, y:y})`; for each empty field.

Comment: Note that You call `grid.init()` with `COLS` and `ROWS`, but in the `setFood()` function You use `canvas.Width` and `canvas.Height`.

Comment: Your assertion about width and height is incorrect. The correct ranges are used everywhere.

Comment: Ok, am I missing something or You missed the `return` keyword in the `grid.get()` method ;)?

Comment: Sometimes the most obvious code errors are really hard to spot :P.

Answer (score 1):

Let me help you debug:

`grid.set(FOOD, randPos.x, randPos.y);` is giving you an error saying you're trying to get the x property from something that's undefined.

Okay, so `randPos` is undefined.

`randPos` comes from `empty[Math.floor(Math.random()*empty.length)];`.

`empty` is an array created inside a nested for loop: `empty.push({x:x, y:y});`. Do you see where `x` is coming from?

As Lukasz points out, there's only a specific case where an array dereference like that is undefined. What if you try doing something like

```
var a = [];
console.log(a[0]);
```

?

And the reason `empty` is empty? No grid cell `=== EMPTY`.

```
 get: function(x,y){
     this._grid[x][y];
 }
```

Because of a missing `return`.

Answer (score 0):

New answer. Check out your function

```
    get: function(x,y){
        this._grid[x][y];
    }
```

and compare it with the one in the video you linked

```
    get: function(x,y){
        return this._grid[x][y];
    }
```

You need to add the return part, otherwise the function will return `undefined`and the array called `empty` won't get any content so your random number generator will suggest you use empty[0], which is `undefined`.

Last answer was replacing randPos.x with randPos["x"] but as informed by bbill in the comments below, that's not it.

Comment: Javascript supports `.` or `[]` notation in cases like these. Problematic cases I know of are when the field is a number, then use `[]` only.